# how to pass value to converter which is a Property in the element which was bound

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

iv'e got a group of Shapes  , i need to decide which stay visible and which hidden 
according to tow conditions (this will represent a dice visual )

(1) the value they receive via binding from their data context .

(2) the value  of their place in the group which i saved for each shape in it's Tag property

i need the converter to get the Tag Property as a parameter for each Shape

**my binding :( INCORRECT )**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter}}"></Setter>
 </Style>
```

**My Shapes :**

```
 <Canvas DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.Dice1,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}">
      <Ellipse Tag="1" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="2" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="20"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="3" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="35"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="4" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="5" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="5"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="6" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="20"></Ellipse>
      <Ellipse Tag="7" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="35"></Ellipse>
   </Canvas>
```

my converter should not be of interest all it does is return Visible or Hidden According to the 
dice value and the place of the Dot on the dice.

any ideas how i can send the converter the tag property or alternatively reference it with in the converter ?

thanks in advance .

EDIT :

i ended up explicitly setting the binding in the markup of each ellipse :

```
<Canvas DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.Dice1,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}">
     <Ellipse Tag="1" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Visibility="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter},ConverterParameter=1}"></Ellipse>
     <Ellipse Tag="2" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="20" Visibility="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter},ConverterParameter=2}"></Ellipse>
     <Ellipse Tag="3" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="35" Visibility="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter},ConverterParameter=3}"></Ellipse>
 </Canvas>
```

still if any one as any idea how to incorporate this into the ellipse's Style in order to avoid all this code repeat please let me know . thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a Multi-binding:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <WPFSampleExplorer:MyDiceInputToVisualConverter x:Key="MyDiceInputToVisualConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                    <Binding />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Page.DataContext>
    <Samples:DiceViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Tag="1" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="2" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="20" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="3" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="4" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="5" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="5" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="6" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="20" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Tag="7" Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="35" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
</Canvas>

public class DiceViewModel
{
    // properties here
}

public class MyDiceInputToVisualConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(values[0]);  // This outputs 1,2,3,..7
        Debug.WriteLine(values[1]);  // This is your DiceViewModel

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: thanks  
i'm new to this didn't figure out the syntax to reference the tag property .
would you use the tag property like iv'e done or could you think of a better way to store that value ?

Comment: I'm going out soon.  Post your question.  Someone will help.

Comment: Type 'drag and drop wpf' into Google.  You'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the ConverterParameter, your Converter will receive the full object (the Ellipse). Then do a cast of your Value to Ellipse and get your Tag.

Comment: it will receive it as the parameter ?

Comment: no , the value given to the constructor would be the value of the 
Property Dice1 in my DataSource which is bound to the Canvas

Comment: Sorry... it seems I misundertood you. If what you mean is to Bind to the Dice (in your datacontext) and to the Tag (in the ellipse) you have to use MultiBinding... check this http://csainty.blogspot.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html

Comment: i edited the question , now that iv'e fixed the binding 
the datacontext of the canvas is Dice1 it's of property of the element bound to Canvas's Ancestor . ( I Checked with snoop the data context is fine ) 

now what i want is to bind each visible property of each ellipse 
the value given is decided by the value of Dice1 and the value of the current Ellipse stated in it's Tag attribute .