# Converter never called when binding to Relative source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

**My Binding :**

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="Ancestor">     
      <StackPanel.Resources>      
          <converters:DiceInputToVisualConverter x:Key="MyDiceInputToVisualConverter" />   

          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=/, Converter={StaticResource  MyDiceInputToVisualConverter},FallbackValue=Visible}"></Setter> 
          </Style>  
     <StackPanel.Resources>
     <StackPanel>
           <Canvas DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.Dice1,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}">                                           
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5"></Ellipse>
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="20"></Ellipse>
           </Canvas>
     </StackPanel>
```

**the DataContext :**

```
  Ancestor.DataContext = game ;
```

**the converter :**

```
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
        int dice = int.Parse(value.ToString());
        if (dice == 3)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Hidden;
     }
```

**my data source :**

```
  public Class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     private int dice1;
     public int Dice1
     {
         get { return dice1; }
         set
         {
             dice1 = value;
             if (PropertyChanged != null)
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dice1"));
        }
     }
   }
```

the binding is fine when i checked it with snoop the ellipse's DataContext had the desired value

but still the Converter is never called any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you should be using `Path=/`? This notation means the currently selected item of the default collection view.

Comment: i saw that in some example , i'll change it and let you know

Comment: @Phil 
while where on the subject 
would you mind taking a look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602410/how-to-pass-value-to-converter-which-is-a-property-in-the-element-which-was-boun/9602553#comment12184941_9602553

Answer (score 0):

I see you have called a static resource

```
StaticResource MyDiceInputToVisualConverter
```

Where have you declared this resource. for example in the Window.Resources section Like the following.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Converters that are used on the MainWindow. -->
    <Converters:MyDiceInputToVisualConverter x:Key="MyDiceInputToVisualConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: here you go look at the edit 
i thought this to be redundant , so i only gave some of the markup 
to show the general idea if i was to place a converter in a place 
where it could not be reached the framework would notify me of it
with a scurvily blue line.